# ListView, обработчик нажатия

Tags: c++, winapi

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на элемент из ListView, нужная мне кнопка стала активной, при выборе другого элемента — неактивной.

Какой обработчик нужно использовать и какие сообщение нужно обрабатывать?

Comment: там же есть событие `OnClick` можете использовать его

Comment: @Saidolim: ТС скорее всего имеет в виду [вот этот `ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, да, Вы правы. Не подскажете что нужно использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ловите сообщение `WM_NOTIFY`, код `LVN_ITEMCHANGED`

```
NMLISTVIEW* lpStateChange = reinterpret_cast<NMLISTVIEW*>(lParam);
if ((lpStateChange->uNewState ^  lpStateChange->uOldState) & LVIS_SELECTED) {
    //Делайте, что надо
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А есть какой-то специальный обработчик для WM_NOTIFY, наподобие Cls_OnCommand?

Comment: @Lightness думаю, что нет

Comment: @zende2k,Спасибо, разобрался, все работает! И еще один вопросик: как проверить что ни один из элементов ListView не выделен?

Comment: @Lightness `if ( ::SendMessage(hwndListView, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, -1, MAKELPARAM(LVNI_SELECTED, 0))==-1){`